# Database T-Log is full due to 'Active_transaction'. SQL server is using new T-log file first rather than old

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I had a SSIS process which failed due to T-log file Full for the Stage database. T-log file max growth is limited to 510GB however only 180-200 GB of t-log file space is getting used everyday.
Even though T-log file had an enough space but it was failing with T-log FULL error. in order to troubleshoot I've added second T-log file (549 GB) to the new drive.
My understanding is that SQL server will use first T-log file first and once it is reached to max limit then only it will start using 2nd T-log file however I noticed that it started using new T-log file rather than old first. It does not look like normal behavior.
How does SQL server decide to use old T-log file or new T-log file first?

SQL server version:- SQL server 2012 SP4

[image]

Comment: Are you routinely backing up the transaction log? What does the [log_reuse_wait_desc](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/my-favorite-system-column-log_reuse_wait_desc/) column say in sys.databases for that database?

Comment: It's a Simple recovery model. Log_reuse_Wait_Desc column says active transaction for the database. It's an active transaction  that's a part of  SSIS package process.

Comment: How long has the transaction been open for? `DBCC OPENTRAN WITH TABLERESULTS;`

Comment: Transaction was open for about 100-120 min.  I re-ran the package after adding new T-log file to the new drive and process completed successfully and it only used 182 GB of new T-log file space. I still don't know                                                      (1) Why process was failing with T-log full even though T-log file size is set to 500 GB ?                                                                                                                                          (2) Why would SQL server start using new T-log file rather than old T-Log file first?

Comment: That's a really long transaction. An open transaction will prevent the Transaction Log from truncating Can you not batch it up into sections?

Comment: That's what I've been thinking by inserting data into small batch rather than one single statement. I never had an issue before where T-log gets full even though T-log file has more than enough space.  also,  it only consumed 182 GB of new T-log file while original T-log is empty.  I am not sure why SQL server started using new T-log file instead of old one.

Answer (score 1):

> Why process was failing with T-log full even though T-log file size is set to 500 GB

Is Replication or CDC enabled for the database?

```
select name, is_published, is_cdc_enabled
from sys.databases
```

> Why would SQL server start using new T-log file rather than old T-Log file first?

Because the old one was full.

Comment: Replication/CDC is not enabled for the database.  Old T-log file was empty. I've added current file size image in original question. as we can see, original file was empty (33 GB) but SQL server started using second T-log (new one) file.